# Как в библиотеке Python прочитать f-строку?

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, pytorch, speechbrain, f-strings

Пишу скрипт сравнения двух файлов с голосами. И вот какое дело. Сначала я для эксперимента непосредственно передаю в метод сравнения два файла:

```
score, prediction = verification.verify_files('/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers/spk7/spk_7_track_3.wav', '/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers/spk8/spk_8_track_1.wav')
```

На этом этапе всё хорошо: получаю ожидаемые ответы (сравнение происходит).

Но стоит лишь написать цикл прохода по файлам из разных папок, где использую f-строку для указания на сравниваемые файлы, как получаю ошибку (может свидетельствовать об ошибке в имени файла или пути к нему):

> RuntimeError: Error loading audio file: failed to open file spk_1_track_3.wav

Структура такова, что в корневой директории `speakers` лежат папки `spk1`, `spk2`, `spk3` и т.д., чьи файлы сравниваем (в каждой из папок - по 4 файла с голосами людей).

Что возможно исправить? Вот код:

```
# подход распознавания на основе ECAPA: сравниваем свои голоса 
!pip install speechbrain
from speechbrain.pretrained import SpeakerRecognition
import os
from itertools import combinations


num_true=0
num_total=0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers'):
    if not files:
        continue
    res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей: [(файл 1, файл 2), (файл 1, файл 3)...(файл 3, файл 4)]
    # print(res)

    for tuples in res:         # идем по каждому картежу в списке
        verification = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
    # print(f'{tuples[0]}', f'{tuples[1]}')
        score, prediction = verification.verify_files(f'{tuples[0]}', f'{tuples[1]}')
        num_total+=1
        if prediction == tensor([True]):
            num_true+=1

    if num_total !=0:
      accuracy = num_true/num_total
      print(accuracy)
    else:
      print('На ноль делить нельзя')
```

Comment: Вы первом случае вы передавали пути к файлам вместе с каталогом. Во втором случае передаёте только имена без каталогов.

Comment: `f'{tuples[0]}'` -> `os.path.join(root, tuples[0])`.

Comment: @Станислав Володарский? спасибо - весьма дельное замечание. 
Теперь у меня поначалу идет расчет (более 2- минут сравниваю файлы), затем дважды выводится `0.0` и `0.0`, после чего ошибка с загрузкой файла повторяется. правда, явно проходя часть папок спикеров. То есть первые папки его устраивают, а `spk3` - почему-то нет

Comment: Выведите пары файлов для сравнения, подождите ошибку, вопроизведите её прямым вызовом. Отладка, в общем.